# Casting in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, casting

I want to check multiple controls state in one method, in C# this would be accomplished like so:

```
if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked == true)
{
    // Do something...
}
else
{
    // Do something else...
}
```

So how can I accomplish this in VB?

Comment: The more experience I get in VB the less I find myself casting controls like this. I know it's not what you asked but you could just:

If Me.CheckBoxOfMine.Checked Then...

Comment: @rvarcher: I personally don't like VB, I hope I don't get to much experience in it. No offense, just my opinion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C#:

```
(CheckBox)sender
```

VB:

```
CType(sender, CheckBox)
```

Comment: Just to clarify is Ctype is IL equivalent of (int)x boxing? or DirectCast. I thought DirectCast is the exact equivalent of this.

Comment: This casts are not equivalent. The VB version is actually a lexical cast, not a CLR cast.

Comment: The C#  (CheckBox) -style cast lives somewhere in between DirectCast and CType().  DirectCast is _more_ strict, CType is closer (not the same as) to Convert.To____()

Comment: Wanted to refine my early comment. In this case the casts are equivalent. As a general rule though they are not as CType will consider certain lexical casts in addition to actual CLR hierarchy and conversion operators.

Comment: As a VB programmer I would use DirectCast in this circumstance.

Answer (score 13):

VB actually has 2 notions of casting.

1. CLR style casting
2. Lexical Casting

CLR style casting is what a C# user is more familiar with.  This uses the CLR type system and conversions in order to perform the cast.  VB has DirectCast and TryCast equivalent to the C# cast and as operator respectively.

Lexical casts in VB do extra work in addition to the CLR type system.  They actually represent a superset of potential casts.  Lexical casts are easily spotted by looking for the C prefix on the cast operator: CType, CInt, CString, etc ...  These cast, if not directly known by the compiler, will go through the VB run time.  The run time will do interpretation on top of the type system to allow casts like the following to work

```
Dim v1 = CType("1", Integer)
Dim v2 = CBool("1")
```

Comment: MSDN appears to differ with you on this, as DirectCast requires type equivalence (or inheritance). CType requires compile-time checking, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb(VS.80).aspx. The runtime is not involved.

Comment: @Adam, The documentation is incorrect. CType can be a lexical conversion and does involve the VB runtime. Try the following "Dim b as Integer = CType("42", Integer)". This both runs and involves the VB runtime

Answer (score 2):

[Adam Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748725/casting-in-visual-basic/748732#748732) is correct, also [`DirectCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x(VS.71).aspx) is available to you.

Comment: Right. However, CType is generally more analogous, as casting in C# will use explicit conversions as long as you have the target object in the context of a convertible type (ie, not as just "object"). DirectCast won't use conversions, but CType will.

Answer (score 2):

DirectCast will perform the conversion at compile time but can only be used to cast reference types.
Ctype will perform the conversion at run time (slower than converting at compile time) but is obviously useful for convertng value types.
In your case "sender" is a reference type so DirectCast would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Casting in VB.net uses the keyword `ctype`.
So the C# statement `(CheckBox)sender` is equivalent to `ctype(sender,CheckBox)` in VB.net.

Therefore your code in VB.net is:

```
if ctype(sender,CheckBox).Checked =True Then
    ' Do something...
else
    ' Do something else...
End If
```