# Difference between Parsing, Converting and CType()

Tags: vb.net, casting

What's the difference between  `Int32.Parse(a)`, `CType(a,int)` and `Convert.ToInt32(a)`? And when we can use them? What is the equivalent for CType in C# ?

Comment: Be aware that [reposting a closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945211/difference-among-directcast-trycast-ctype-convertto-and-parsing) may annoy some people. I suppose you are trying to find out about `ConvertTo` and `Int32.Parse`?

Comment: There is no exact equivalent of `CType` in C#. Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/748785/15639 ?

Comment: That part of your question not answered by John Woo is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/423820/256431

Answer (score 2):

**Int32.parse(string)**

> Int32.Parse (string s) method converts the string representation of a
>   number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. When s is a null
>   reference, it will throw ArgumentNullException. If s is other than
>   integer value, it will throw FormatException. When s represents a
>   number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, it will throw
>   OverflowException.

**Convert.ToInt32(string)**

> Convert.ToInt32(string s) method converts the specified string
>   representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent. This calls in turn
>   Int32.Parse () method. When s is a null reference, it will return 0
>   rather than throw ArgumentNullException. If s is other than integer
>   value, it will throw FormatException. When s represents a number less
>   than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, it will throw
>   OverflowException.