# Change backColor of Sender TextBox

Tags: vb6

I have a lot of textboxes which i wanted them to change the backColor when focused.

This is the code when load the form

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    For Each c  As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then 
            AddHandler c.Enter, AddressOf Me.changeBg
            AddHandler c.Leave, AddressOf Me.restoreBg
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And this the listener

```
Sub changeBg(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Dim c As Control = sender
    'sender.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(&HFFFF9D)
End Sub
```

How to get the textbox control and change its backColor? because I get the sender as an object

Comment: VB6? ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(&HFFFF9D). Add error handling as you see fit.

Comment: @jac altough this is c# style the meaning is the same. To cast the element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting in visual basic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748725/casting-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 2):

I finally added a correct casting for vb

```
Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
tb.BackColor  = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(&HFFFF9D)
```

As it do it here

Cast event sender to control http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0260__GUI/Casteventsendertocontrol.htm

And here
[Casting in visual basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748725/casting-in-visual-basic)