# c# to vb.net error: 'clsInput' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Dim inputObj As localObj.clsInput = New localObj.clsInput()
Dim webInputObj As webObj.clsInput = New webObj.clsInput()
```

**Get Error Here** when try copy object

```
webInputObj = (webObj.clsInput)deal.CopyObjTo(webInputObj, inputObj)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting in visual basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748725/casting-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 0):

```
webInputObj = CType(deal.CopyObjTo(webInputObj, inputObj), webObj.clsInput)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360251/8371915)